# from / where Can i call static class methods in a class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have the below code in the same namespace.

```
public static class usercls
{

        public static int testc()
    {

        int s=1;
    }
}

    public class User : Page
    {

        private static User user;     

        int s=usercls.testc();//why not accessible here?


    }
```

I'm unable to access the static class outside of the class. Can someone help me to identify this?

Comment: Show how you are trying to call it.

Comment: in the user calss i tried to access it using  int s=usercls.testc();

Comment: It should be perfectly accessible ([once you fix all other errors, anyway](http://ideone.com/b0Z996)). What error do you get?

Comment: `testc` won't compile, as it doesn't return a value. But once you fix that, this works fine. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I assume he gets a testc does not return a value Error. He should write return 1; or return s;

Comment: @TomCruise: That static member is indeed accessible in that context.  (Once you correct other unrelated errors so the code can compile in the first place.)  What's actually preventing this from working?  What *actual error* do you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi the function testc() doesnt return any value.
It should look like this

```
public static int testc()
{
    int s=1;
    return s;
}
```

or like this

```
public static int testc()
{
    return 1;
}
```

After that your code should compile.

Other classes cannot access the class functions of usercls because the compiler did not compiled it, because there was an error, once you fix that error, it will be accessible from all the other classes.

Also
You are trying to call it directly in your other class, the call should be within a function like so:

```
public class User : Page
{

    private static User user;     
    public User()
    {
        int s=usercls.testc();//why not accessible here?
    }
}
```